# How to keep text selected/highlighted when a modal pops up

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am creating a document writer and am using `document.execCommand` to create a link. What I want is for a user to select/ highlight a bit of text, click a button to add a link to that piece of text (through a modal) and then have that piece of text transformed into a link when they add it - something like you see with Medium and other blog sites.

My issue is that I can highlight a piece of text, click the link button, a modal pops up but because the focus is then on the modal input it loses focus of the highlighted text and so I have no way of adding the link to the originally high lighted text.

**component.html**

```
<button mat-icon-button [ngClass]="linkSelected ? 'selected' : 'unselected' (click)="onClickLink()"> <mat-icon svgIcon="link"></mat-icon> </button>

<div id="article" cdkFocusInitial contentEditable="true" spellcheck="false">
```

**component.ts**

```
onClickLink() {

const name = '';
const link = '';

//Opens modal
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddResourceComponent, {
  data: {name, link},
  maxWidth: '100vw',
  maxHeight: '100vh'
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result) {
    document.execCommand('createLink', false, result.link);
  }
});
```

}

If anyone has any ideas how to accomplish this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably achieve this by setting around the block of text  a new html balise like `<mark></mark>` with id or distinguing data that you can look after when you need it. also `<mark>` give you the selected aspect . and you can add some style to it.

hope it help